# how can my table enteties inherit the table class?

Tags: html, css

Here's my css:

```css
table.mytable { 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 24px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

caption.mytable { 
    font-size: larger; 
    margin: 5px auto; 
}

th.mytable, td.mytable, thead.mytable { 
    background: #3e83c9;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px 11px;
    text-align: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

tr.mytable:nth-child(odd) { 
    background: #ecf6fc; 
}

tr.mytable:hover { 
    background: #bcd4ec; 
} 

td.mytable { 
    padding: 6px 11px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #95bce2;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The css style works fine, the problem I'm having is that in my html I have to assign a class to each `<tr>`, `<td>`, `<th>`, etc..Is there a way where I only have to assign the class to the table? do I have to modify my css code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like that:

```css
table.mytable th, table.mytable td, table.mytable thead{
    background: #3e83c9;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px 11px;
    text-align: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

See [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Thanks. I almost got it working except for this part: `table.mytable tr.alt td {` it's not applying the `background` color to the alternative rows.

Comment: @user962449: Alternative rows? Do you mean `:nth-child`?